# How to get a schengen visa from non-Schengen area for Erasmus students?

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas

Next semester i will be an Erasmus+ student in non-Schengen area. To be an Erasmus student can increase my chances to get a Schengen visa from another embassy?

Comment: All other things being equal, it increases your chances. We don't know the specifics of your case and we can't guess what they have in their databases on you.

Comment: Actually, i have never been in Schengen countries. I have been only in Georgia and Russia several times without any problem. My erasmus university is in Romania. But Romania isn't Schengen area. But i would like to travel to some Schengen countries.

Comment: When you are resident in Romania, you can make your application from Romania. You would have to make it credible that you will return *to Romania*, which might be easier if you are a student in good standing.

Comment: @o.m. That sounds like an answer

Comment: @Traveller, there is not much information in my answer. Yes, he can apply. No, we can't guess the odds, much less give certain advice..